# Can code optimize code?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, packages, meta-programming

Are there functions, programs or packages that deal with optimizing mathematica code i.e. re-writing ineffecive or convoluted code.
-This question has haunted me since I joined SE.

The background for my question being the following:
I have noticed that a considerable amount of answers and comments deal with trying to improve a given code sample. It is fascinating to see in how many ways a particular problem can be solved and often there is an unspoken and cheerful competition as who can write the fastest and or shortest code that does the job. - This creates an extremely creative and positive atmosphere here.
Given the above, the answer to my question could be **no**.

However:
Since Mathematica must be considered extremely powerful with, patterns, rules and an extensive set of built-in functions and advanced algorithms, it seems quite reasonable to expect that someone has tried to write a code optimizing program, at least on a very basic level. So the answer could be **yes**.

So to recap: 
Does there exist any program/function/package that give the user feedback in better or alternative code?

Comment: My guess is probably not. A significant obstacle is Mathematica's symbolic/interpreted design, meaning you often cannot tell what code is doing until you evaluate it, and the same block of code might evaluate completely differently depending on the arguments you pass. I suppose you could look for certain types of optimizations, but you would have to make some strong assumptions and the scope would necessarily be quite limited.

Comment: I'll be thrilled to see a code that can effectively do that.  I don't think it is impossible, but provided the different ways a problem can be solved and the potential set of design parameters that can make a solution better than other, I think that it would be better to create a list of community selected core problems and associated solutions with evaluation comments on pertinent design parameters.

Comment: FWIW, there's [``Experimental`OptimizeExpression``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Experimental+OptimizeExpression).

Comment: @mfvonh It requires a certain amount of ignorance to be able to ask a question like this. Nothing frees you from the shackles of a complex reality as a limited insight in the matter. However the question has always intrigued me and I'm hoping something good will come out of it.

Comment: `Simplify`/`FullSimplify` also act according to their given `ComplexityFunction`. So, the problem is in that sense reduced to correctly expressing your idea of complexity.

Comment: There may be some cases where given some Mathematica built-ins `F1, F2, F3, ... , FN` possibly each with its own arguments, a rule to reduce the composition `FN@* ... @*F4@*F3@*F2@*F1` to a single builtin `G` could be constructed- even in some appropriately general case if you're lucky. I'm pretty comfortable that I'll never need an auto-optimizer, but what would definitely be useful is a code-readability optimizer/beautifier for all those awful huge differential equations we get on here.

Comment: @Histograms  Being rather ignorant of the matter (optimization), my train of thought was the following: Since Mathematica code is compiled to some appropriate C equivalent and that code is then optimized in some way, it would be reasonable to be able to reverse that optimized C-code, back to the best representation of it in Mathematica and thereby give the user some alternative suggestions of better Mma code. I know this a gross simplification but I thought it must be possible to achieve some degree of optimization.

Comment: @MathLind What makes you think Mathematica code is compiled to C before being executed? From what I understand, only few data types can be `Compile`d. The rest is interpreted I assume. As for some automatic optimization, Google "mathematica common subexpression elimination" - I assume the Mathematica interpreter will by default not eliminate any common subexpressions because they could have side-effects, and it wants to generate correct `Trace`s. It's probably like running your C program in Debug mode in that regard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the Wolfram Technology Conference 2016 there were two presentations that imply that with the next-generation Wolfram Compiler there will be some limited ability to have code optimize code.

## Presentation 1: Replacing your code with a more efficient version

The compiler runs an analysis on your code looking for patterns that can be optimized. For example, the following code squares the elements in a list and then adds 3:

```
foo=#+3&;
bar=#^2&;
Map[foo, Map[bar, Range@10]]
```

Because foo and bar have no side effects, the compiler symbolically rewrites the code to use "loop fusion" and expresses line 3 as:

```
Map[foo@*bar, Range@10]
```

This new expression is shorter and traverses over the list only once. 
In the demonstration at the conference they showed that there is intermediate step which contains the loop-fused expression. Thus it would be possible replace your original code with the new optimized expression, which is more effective.

## Presentation 2: Deconvoluting Code

There has been significant effort invested in trying to understand if two code segments are equivalent. The presentation talked about an online programming challenge system that evaluated not just test cases, but true code equivalence.

The system the presenter demonstrated used systems of transformation rules to change code into a canonical form that could be compared to a "correct" solution.
For example, his system would take either of the following expressions:

```
Range@10
Table[i,{i,1,10}]
```

And through rule transformations convert them into the "canonical form"

```
Table[i,{i,1,10,1}]
```

Which is equivalent to the previous expressions.
Since this technology exists, it would also be possible to reverse the rules, and take the rather convoluted expression

```
Table[i,{i,1,10,1}]
```

And apply:

```
Table[a___,{i_, b_, c_, 1}]->Table[a,{i,b,c}]
Table[i,{i_, 1,  n_,}]->Range[n]
```

To get the clearer Range[10] function back out.

## Conclusion

There are indeed programs that attempt to optimize code and there exists efforts underway that would allow for more advanced code deconvolution. Many of these methods however relied on freedom from 'side effects' common in state-based procedural programming. Furthermore these projects have not yet developed direct/user-friendly interfaces to give the feedback to the user.